# Paste one video to another on top layer

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I have over 100+ videos and i need to paste one 5 sec avi video on top layer of every video (something like watermark or animated logo). It can be performed with Adobe Premiere, but its too long and stupid. Where i can find good framework to work with video to perform this (any language)? Or any other method to do it? Maybe 'ffmpeg' can help? Any help, links, documentations would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear on what you mean by 5 sec avi video on top layer. 
I am guessing your watermark is 5 seconds long and 100+ videos are arbitary length and you want to put the first in some location on the second

ffmpeg has an overlay filter.: Here is the documentation

Overlay one video on top of another.

It takes two inputs and one output, the first input is the "main" video on which the second input is overlayed.

It accepts the parameters: x:y[:options].

x is the x coordinate of the overlayed video on the main video, y is the y coordinate. x and y are expressions containing the following parameters:

‘main_w, main_h’

```
main input width and height
```

‘W, H’

```
same as main_w and main_h
```

‘overlay_w, overlay_h’

```
overlay input width and height
```

‘w, h’

```
same as overlay_w and overlay_h
```

options is an optional list of key=value pairs, separated by ":".

The description of the accepted options follows.

‘rgb’

```
If set to 1, force the filter to accept inputs in the RGB color space. Default value is 0.
```

Be aware that frames are taken from each input video in timestamp order, hence, if their initial timestamps differ, it is a a good idea to pass the two inputs through a setpts=PTS-STARTPTS filter to have them begin in the same zero timestamp, as it does the example for the movie filter.

Follow some examples:

```
# draw the overlay at 10 pixels from the bottom right
# corner of the main video.
overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10
```

This one worked for me fine:
ffmpeg -i ./external/bb_high.mp4 -i external/small.mp4 -strict -2 -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' output.mp4

But end of 5 seconds I think the last frame remains in the overlay.

This is where gstreamer option is a better one. There is a videomixer element available to do exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: ok. I will check ffmpeg documentation. thanks for the hint. thanks. will accept your answer if there will be no other good ways to do it.

Comment: @LLAlive, gstreamer will definitely help you do it. Am not sure if you are comfortable with it. A command line pipeline should allow you to do with and not have any limitations that ffmpeg has. But it can be a long road if you don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Not using ffmpeg, but with Expression Encoder you can overlay an image, or 'moving image' on top of the video, or you can easily stitch two videos together.

[MSDN link - Add visual overlays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341426%28v=expression.30%29.aspx)
[How to Video](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc460712.aspx)
[MSDN link - Using the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602440%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)
[Wade Wegner blog post](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/overlay-text-on-video-using-expression-encoder-4/)